# Is this correct use of for which?

Tags: prepositions

If the following use of "for which" is not correct, how to rephrase?

> This is why I think COVID will be with humans forever. We can't even get rid of measles, diphtheria, and cholera, all for which we
>   have had vaccinations forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case *For which* is a pretty good choice. You might change the phrase around to read "...and we've had vaccines for each of these forever."